# What can cause all routes to return Unauthenticated error when upgraded from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I just upgraded my app from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3 and followed all the steps.
The one that seems to be the cause of the issue I'm facing is Auth Middleware. I did change the class that should be executed.
But for some reason, all the routes are returning "Unauthenticated" error.

I'm not fetching logged in user in the constructor of any controller class.
In fact, none of my controller class have a constructor.
What can be causing this problem?

Comment: Have you checked your routes for **`middleware('auth')`** being assigned to any of the routes?

Comment: Yes, it is assigned to all the routes.

Comment: It is still auth and not "auth:api" or "auth:web".

Comment: Have you tried removing the middleware from the route and accessing the url? Does it still give you unauthenticated error?

Comment: If You have `middleware('auth')` added to any of your routes you will not be able to visit them until you are an authenticated user.

Comment: Removing Middleware throws 500 error because it can not find the user.
I'm using auth()->user(). It always returns Null. But login page redirects to home page because it detects that user is not a guest user.

Comment: Adding "web" middleware wherever I've "auth" middleware solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "web" middleware wherever I've "auth" middleware solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The two default authentication controllers provided with the framework have been split into four smaller controllers. This change provides cleaner, more focused authentication controllers by default. The easiest way to upgrade your application to the new authentication controllers is to grab a fresh copy of each controller from GitHub and place them into your application.

You should also make sure that you are calling the Auth::routes() method in your  routes/web.php file. This method will register the proper routes for the new authentication controllers.

Once these controllers have been placed into your application, you may need to re-implement any customizations you made to these controllers. For example, if you are customizing the authentication guard that is used for authentication, you may need to override the controller's guard method. You can examine each authentication controller's trait to determine which methods to override.

[From laravel 5.2 to 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0)